# How to load public certificate from pem file?

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography, bouncycastle, public-key

I was trying to extract RES public key from the file below

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
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
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Here is the code i did..

```
public static PublicKey loadPublicKeyFromFile(File publicKeyFile) throws Exception {

    FileReader file = new FileReader(publicKeyFile);
    PemReader reader = new PemReader(file);
    X509EncodedKeySpec caKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(reader.readPemObject().getContent());
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey caKey = kf.generatePublic(caKeySpec);
    return caKey;
}
```

But It throws out

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID

What's the appropriate way to extract RES Public key from a file..

Comment: It's a certificate, not a key. Load it as a certificate and then call `getPublicKey()`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

An X.509 certificate and an X509EncodedKeySpec are quite different structures, and trying to parse a cert as a key won't work.
Java's [`X509EncodedKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html) is actually SubjectPublicKeyInfo from X.509 or equivalent and more convenient [PKIX](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1) also linked from [Key](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Key.html), which is only a small part of a certificate.

What you need to do is read and parse the cert and then extract the pubkey from the cert.
Standard SunJCE `CertificateFactory` can do it
(and can read either PEM or DER to boot) like this:

```
CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream (args[0]);
X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(is);
PublicKey key = cer.getPublicKey();
is.close();
// add error handling as appropriate, try-with-resources is often good
```

If you have BouncyCastle you can use its provider the same way (just add a second argument to `.getInstance` or set the default provider list order), or you can use `PEMParser` with `JcaX509CertificateConverter` -- which effectively does the same thing, internally running the data through a `CertificateFactory`.

Comment: the input stream should be closed

Comment: @ch271828n: I originally meant that to be included in 'to taste', but I might as well be explicit, and found other useful updates as well -- thanks.

Comment: by the way, close it in finally{} or use the `try(...){}`

Answer (score 0):

With Sun JVM it is also possible with

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl;

InputStream is = ...
X509Certificate crt = new X509CertImpl(is);
```

, although I'd prefer the accepted answer as JVM implementation-independent one.

Under the hood, in Sun JVM, `CertificateFactory`(more precisely, `X509Factory`) does instantiate `X509CertImpl` , but there is very subtle difference between the two approaches: `CertificateFactory` caches X509 Certificate instances by binary content of the input stream, the one that can be retrieved by `cer.getEncoded()`.

The cache can be cleared by

```
fact.generateCertificate(null);
```

Comment: It's 2022 by now, and 2021 in the given answer; *we know we should not be using Sun internal classes by now*.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I never said we should use this way. Like I said, I'd prefer the accepted answer's way. Just wanted to look a little bit "under the hood" and point out that in most popular Sun JVM there is a caching in place.